# How to check the return value in a php function

Tags: php

here is my piece of php code:

```
Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function ($reader) {
    some_function();
});
```

my question is how to get the return value of some_function() and to check it if it is true, right after the execution of the Excel::load() block ? But please without the use of try-catch-block !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a returnvalue argument by reference, so that you can access it outside of the callback

```
$returnValue = null;
Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function ($reader) use (&$returnValue) {
    $returnValue = some_function();
});
if ($returnValue) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: hi Mark, unfortunately this does not work. before i made the if-check i made a var_dump($returnValue) and it gives me always null :(

Comment: sorry my bad. I have used the & operator :)